# Is there any FORCAST function available in Pine-Script?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert an existing script into Pine-Script, and I am currently stuck in a function which is FORCAST, where I don't know what it is trying to do.
Possible if I post the partial script here and if there is anyone that is able to interpret it?

Comment: You can use the `offset` argument of the `plot` function types. However, it is hard to tell without seeing any code or description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually...

FORCAST (X, N)
Linear regression
N-period linear regression prediction for X.
Note:
1, N is a valid value, but the current number of k lines is less than N, this function returns a null value;
2. When N is 0, the function returns a null value;
3. N is a null value, and the function returns a null value;
4.N can be a variable
example:
FORCAST (CLOSE, 5);

Comment: This is what I have found on website. and not able to convert it or find the similat function in Pine Script

Answer (score 0):

if what you're looking for is indeed a linear regression like the Excel FORECAST function, please have a look on this example:

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#linear-regression

Normally such functions should have (at least) the following inputs:

1. known vector of X values (inputs)
2. known vector of Y values (outputs)
3. user X value for which the function will return a forecasted Y value

The example in the link will give you a fairly complete implementation of linear regression in Pine-script, but note it is meant to draw a line instead of making forecasts. You'll need to get some hands-on if you want to convert it into a function that returns you a certain Y value instead of the line.